# img "glued" to the division on hover. How to make it appear elsewhere while maintaining the relation

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I'm awfully new to the whole game and approach problems pretty much everyday. Most of the time I solve them with google, learning a lot, but this time I can't find anything.

So, I've got this lovely header that moves to the right and makes some space for another element. I'd like this element (the bonobo head) to appear when I hover over the header.

So, I set the display of the image to `none`, and `block` on `header:hover`, but the image seems glued to the header.

I would like it to appear next to it, in any given location. What do ?

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #54e954;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.header:hover {
  left: 15%;
  background-color: #d0f307;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.header:hover .photo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="h1header">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Bonobo-Head.jpg" class="photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want it to look like ? If you want this, I did it using the display flex structure.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;  /* added */
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  left: 0%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #54e954;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.header:hover {
  left: 15%;
  background-color: #d0f307;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.header:hover .photo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="h1header">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Bonobo-Head.jpg" class="photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated : With Javascript, you can better control hover and hoverout operations. Here's an example I've prepared for you. By the way, I had to get the img tag out of the header tag. You can see the additions I've made.

```js
let header = document.querySelector(".header");
let imageContainer = document.querySelector(".img-container");
header.onmouseover = function() {
  imageContainer.classList.add("showImage");
}
header.onmouseout = function() {
  imageContainer.classList.remove("showImage");
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  /* added */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #54e954;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.header:hover {
  transform: translateX(15%);
  /* added*/
  background-color: #d0f307;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.img-container.showImage {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Bonobo-Head.jpg" class="photo">
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="h1header">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what it did is: The photo now moved to the  right side of the header division, but it's still in the header division. I tried to move the img into a seperate division, but then it's not showing at all. I want it to appear on the left side, outside the header, when I hover the header.

Thank you nonetheless

Comment: I understand you. But there is a problem. picture in header. When the image is in display block, it will be located in the header and will change the size . There is no escaping it. Because you have defined it in HTML, in header.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Then how do I make an outside-header image appear, when I hover over the header?  So, the image is hidden, but It appears somewhere on the screen when I hover over the header?

Comment: Anyway. I arranged it to be the way you wanted it to be. you can control it.

Comment: Actually, you're right.  This is what I added, in addition to the display: flex

.photo {
position: relative;
display: none;
}

.header:hover  .photo {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
left: -400px;
top: 0px;

}

Comment: it works the way you do it, yes. But to make content responsive, you may have trouble in the future and you will have to value it one by one at a time.